# save data from checkbox into mongoose using MEAN stack

Tags: angularjs, node.js, checkbox, mongoose, mean-stack

i have developped these lines to save selected data from checkbox into mongoose  in the html file

```
 <label ng-repeat="role in roles">
   <input type="checkbox" checklist-model="user.roles" checklist-value="role.id"> {{role.text}}
    </label>
```

in the controller file info.js

```
  $scope.roles = [
{id: 1, text: 'guest'},
{id: 2, text: 'user'},
{id: 3, text: 'customer'},
{id: 4, text: 'admin'}
 ];
 $scope.user = {
  roles: [1,2,3,4]
 };
 langage: $scope.user.roles;
```

in the app.js

```
var langage1= req.body.langage;
console.log (langage1);
```

when i run the program i have this message in the conole :  roles: [ 1, 2, 3, 4 ] while i want the selected label

Comment: Too many missing pieces to this puzzle

Comment: the code is very long and contains many other parts, that is why i have posted only the important

Comment: Well what you posted isn't enough to make sense of what's going on...or exactly what you send or know what is needed to help fix problem. That's why you see no answers yet. Explanation is very poor overall